# Is there any GUI for image processing algorithm before coding?

Tags: image-processing, opencv3.0

I am working on license plate area detection and i use some tutorial like [this link](http://rnd.azoft.com/instant-license-plate-recognition-in-ios-apps/) and i should some thresholding and apply sobel and morphology and so on. my question is :

Is there any GUI tool to manipulate the parameter like kernel size before hard coding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/

Download, and you should be able to try all computer vision algorithms before you code them.